# Changing the time parameter and finding the corresponding hamiltonian

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space, time-evolution

I'm dealing with a problem where I have a (classical) Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ such that, for any scalar function $f(p,q)$,
$$
\dot{f} = \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}t} =\{ f,H \}
$$

If I change the time parameter such that $\mathrm{d}t = N(p,q) \mathrm{d}\tau$, where $\tau$ is the new time coordinate, is there any (easy) way of finding the corresponding Hamiltonian $\tilde{H}$ such that

$$
\mathring{f} = \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = \{ f,\tilde{H} \}~?
$$

Comment: Hi Álvaro. Is this from a reference? Which page? Which context?

Answer (score 0):

Just an ancillary remark: the ease of solving
$$
\{f,H\}= N(p,q)~  \{f,\tilde H \}
$$
may well depend on the particular form of *N(p,q)*, which
*must*, predictably, satisfy the integrability condition(s)
$$
\{N,H\}= 0=\{N,\tilde H\}. \tag{I}
$$

The reason is that, taking *f* to be *q* and *p*, respectively, you need the (sufficient) system of PDEs,
$$
\frac{1}{N} \partial_p H = \partial_p \tilde H ,\\
\frac{1}{N} \partial_q H = \partial_q \tilde H ,
$$
hence,
$$
 \partial_p H = N \partial_p \tilde H ,\\
 \partial_q H = N \partial_q \tilde H .
$$

The integrability of this system of equations follows
differentiation of the upper equations by $\partial_q$ and the lower ones by $\partial_p$, and equating the two, thus obtaining the consistency condition (I).

Choosing suitable integral limits for the boundary conditions, you might get
$$
\tilde H = g(q)+ \int \!\! dp {1\over N} \partial_p H = h(p)+ \int \!\! dq {1\over N} \partial_q H .
$$

For instance, for $N=H$, you get $\tilde H= \ln H$; if $N=\exp (-H)$, you get $\tilde H= \exp H$, and so on.

It sure looks like a homework problem.